# Can't view edit queue in review

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review

Upon clicking on an edit link that has pending edit suggestions, rather than bringing up the modal box for the suggested edit, it brings me to the top of the current page.

[image]

Comment: Saw that too recently. Chromium 15 on Linux here if if matters.

Comment: Does it persist when you refresh the page? Can you post link to that page?

Comment: I see you [successfully rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/134582) that pending suggestion. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I'm not sure _how_ you could link to the specific review view, and the suggested edits are short-lived in general...

Comment: @Mat I've just seen that in the OP profile page, under activity tab --> [reviews filter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/540162/nightfirecat?tab=activity#page_1-filter_reviews). Not sure what you mean by "suggested edits are short-lived"? There is always permanent link to any suggested edit..

Comment: This bug only shows up in the pages in the '/review' section. So you'd need a link to that section, with a post that has a pending edit. Since the contents of the '/review' pages change a lot, and pending edits get approved/rejected pretty fast, I'm not sure how you could link to a page that reproduces the problem. (Maybe it would be easier on the less active sites though)

Comment: I successfully rejected the edit, after visiting the actual Q/A's page, since I couldn't do it from /review - it only doesn't function correctly in /review. I guess I should mention that it behaves like any of the AJAX controls on SO, if you try and use them before the page fully loads, except the page was fully loaded.

Comment: P.S. I'm going to try and find another one out of /review to permalink, but at the time of writing, I've reviewed ~200 posts, and that was the first one that had a pending edit on it.

Comment: I can repro this in Firefox 7.0.1 in `/review` on SF.

Comment: This will be fixed next build